# List column names and count the number of times data was entered on each field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I used this query to list the fields on a table:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, COUNT(*)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Table_Name'
```

But I wanted to add a count for each column names that will count the number of times data was entered on each field. Maybe the better way to say this is the count how many records on each field.

Hope someone can help.

I am expecting something like this

```
Column Name | Count
```

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Comment: What s your MySQL version? Please run `SELECT version();` to check.

Comment: Hi @FanoFN, I am running SQL Server Management Studio 19. Does this helps? I tried running the above script and it gives me version is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are looking for something as follows.

It is generic regardless how many columns a table in question has.

```
USE tempdb;
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tmpTable;

-- DDL and sample data population, start
CREATE TABLE #tmpTable  (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, Shop_1 VARCHAR(20), Shop_2 VARCHAR(20), Shop_3 VARCHAR(20), Shop_4 VARCHAR(20));
INSERT INTO #tmpTable (Shop_1, Shop_2, Shop_3, Shop_4) VALUES
(NULL, 'Nike', 'Adidas', NULL),
(NULL, 'Nike', 'Adidas', 'Asics'),
(NULL, 'Asics', NULL, 'Asics'),
(NULL, 'Nike', NULL, 'Adidas');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT c.value('local-name(.)', 'sysname') AS column_name
    FROM #tmpTable AS t
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT t.* FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE) AS t1(x)
    CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/*') AS t2(c)
)
(
SELECT name AS column_name, NULL AS column_counter
FROM tempdb.sys.columns
WHERE object_id = object_id('tempdb..#tmpTable')
   AND is_nullable = 1
EXCEPT
SELECT column_name, null
FROM rs
)
UNION ALL
SELECT column_name, COUNT(*) AS column_counter
FROM rs
GROUP BY column_name;
```

**Output**

| column_name | column_counter |
| --- | --- |
| Shop_1 | NULL |
| ID | 4 |
| Shop_2 | 4 |
| Shop_3 | 2 |
| Shop_4 | 3 |

Comment: Hi, thank you for this! May I know if the "@tbl" should be replaced by the table name right? I will try this one out and will let you know.

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Hi Yitzhak
May I know how can I address this error?

Msg 252, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Recursive common table expression '@tbl' does not contain a top-level UNION ALL operator.

Completion time: 2023-08-13T19:56:59.0667400-07:00

Comment: Please edit your original question, and add there your T-SQL, simulating my answer.

Comment: Hi Yitzhak,

I was able to make it work. May I know if this one only outputs columns that has a count of more than zero or is not null right?

Is there a way to modify this and include columns with NULL values? Like we could just have it as NULL in count or zero

Comment: I updated the answer to include NULLs. Check it out. In the future, please provide a **minimal reproducible example**.

Comment: Hi thank you. I will keep this in mind